# MEF Container cannot compose parts from Shared Assembly

Tags: c#, import, export, mef

I have 3 projects in my solution:

1- ExporterLib (Class Library)

2- ImporterApp (WPF Application)

3- SharedLib (Class Library)

the first two projects reference "SharedLib" which contains an interface called `ISharedClass` .

Inside "ImporterApp" I have a class called ClassA:

```
public class ClassA
{
    [Import] private ISharedClass part;
}
```

Inside "ExporterLib" I have a class called SharedClassExport:

```
[Export(ISharedClass)]
public class SharedClassExport : ISharedClass
{
    //....
}
```

In ImporterApp I use a DirectoryCatalog referencing ExporterLib.dll file and a container. But when I try to compose the parts of ClassA instance using the container I receive an exception saying:

**1) No exports were found that match the constraint: 
    ContractName    SharedLib.ISharedClass
    RequiredTypeIdentity    SharedLib.ISharedClass**

When I use the debugger to see the parts inside the catalog I see the correct **SharedClassExport** Part, but it's not referencing ISharedClass!

What Should I Do?

P.S. : I want to use MEF and I don't want to merge any of these projects together.

Thanks in advance.

---

SUMMARY:

//Specifying the contract type may be important if
you want to export a type other then the base type,
such as an interface.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.importattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try using [Export(typeof(ISharedClass))] . If you are exporting a type other than a base type, such as interface, it is important to specify the full contract type using typeof. To match the export use [Import(typeof(ISharedClass))]. Please let me know if this worked if not please provide the DirectoryCatalog composition logic you are using?

Comment: Adding  [Export(typeof(ISharedClass))]  alone didn't work. But when I changed the simple [Import] attribute to [Import(typeof(ISharedClass))] It was magically solved. can you describe what happens if I don't explicitly state type of Import I am using? Thanks by the way.

Comment: I am glad I was able to solve the issue. If you see my response closely, I did mention that you have to match the Import to [Import(typeof(ISharedClass))]. This is because you are not exporting a simple type. Your type is inherited from ISharedClass, MEF needs to know about the full contract for properly exporting the type.

Comment: Well what I originally meant was that Why can't MEF just figure it out itself when the type of the part is matching the export... But I looked at this article and I found out "Specifying contract name may be important if you want to export a type other than base type like Interface" ... 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.importattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check the bin folder of ImporterApp after your build. I'm willing to wager that ExporterLib.dll is not in the folder. Since ExporterLib.dll is not a direct dependency of ImporterApp MSBuild doesn't copy it to ImporterApp's bin folder on build. To fix this you have a few choices:

- You can add a reference to ExporterLib in the ImporterApp project.
- If you don't want to add the reference, a post build step on ImporterApp to copy the ExporterLib.dll to the bin directory of ImporterApp would also work.
- You could also setup each project to build to the same directory in the solution structure.

Comment: I was manually copying the ExporterLib.dll to the bin directory of ImporterApp as you stated already... however Soma's approach solved the issue. thanks for your attention.